# PHP - IRC Function

Tags: php, irc

I have been figuring about and trying to make my IRC bot send private messages to % of users on the channel however it's not working.

Here is my script, you will understand it when you see it:

```
<?php

/**
 * Configuration.
 * Pretty self-explanatory
 */

$ircServer = "//";
$ircPort = "6667";
$ircChannel = "#//";

set_time_limit(0);


$msg = $_POST['message'];
$pr = $_POST['percentage'];
$pr /= 100;

$ircSocket = fsockopen($ircServer, $ircPort, $eN, $eS);

if ($ircSocket)
{

    fwrite($ircSocket, "USER Lost rawr.test lol :code\n");
    fwrite($ircSocket, "NICK Rawr" . rand() . "\n");
    fwrite($ircSocket, "JOIN " . $ircChannel . "\n");

    while(1)
    {
        while($data = fgets($ircSocket, 128))
        {
            echo nl2br($data);
            flush();

            // Separate all data
            $exData = explode(' ', $data);

            // Send PONG back to the server
            if($exData[0] == "PING")
            {
                fwrite($ircSocket, "PONG ".$exData[1]."\n");
            }
}
    echo $eS . ": " . $eN;
}
shuffle($users);
$size = count($users);
$target = $size * $pr;
$target = $round($target);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $target; $i++) {
    fwrite($ircSocket, "PRIVMSG " . $users[$i] . " :" . $msg . "\n");
}
?>
```

Evertime I try re-coding it here is the error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampp\htdocs\irc.php on line 55`

I am trying to make a percentage system that will shuffle the % of users on the IRC channel to private message a set % on the shuffle system.

Comment: And that's why you need to indent properly.  If you did, you'd notice there's no closing `}` for the first `if` block...

Comment: Fixed that now, my mistake for not reading it. But the bot wont private message other users on the channel via % shuffle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unexpected $end` means it reached the end of the file and all your blocks (`{}`) weren't closed. It's right, you have more open braces than close braces; you forgot to close one somewhere. Based on the indenting, I think you meant to close your inner `while` loop right after the `if` statement:

```
while(1)
{
    while($data = fgets($ircSocket, 128))
    {
        echo nl2br($data);
        flush();

        // Separate all data
        $exData = explode(' ', $data);

        // Send PONG back to the server
        if($exData[0] == "PING")
        {
            fwrite($ircSocket, "PONG ".$exData[1]."\n");
        }
    } // <-- THIS IS NEW
}
```

---

Just from skimming the code, I don't see anything obviously wrong with the approach, but I didn't actually try it

Comment: I'm not sure if I done the system correctly, will it function?

Comment: Fixed that now, my mistake for not reading it. But the bot wont private message other users on the channel via % shuffle...

Answer (score 1):

you forget the '}' for 
if ($ircSocket) {

Comment: The bot gives me this log when I log into it: :StatServ!stats@Mazzz.com PRIVMSG Rawr20867 :VERSION